# Applying UserDir directive in XAMPP's Apache server

Tags: apache, xampp, mod-userdir

I want to create user directories in an Apache server that are also accessible via the FileZilla FTP server. How do I create these directives and most importantly how do I apply them to Apache?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have mod_userdir installed,
Add in your configuration files add the following: Userdir insert-directory-here
then create the directory specified in the Userdir line in the home directory.
Test out using http://localhost/~insert-directory-name-here